# Does AC consume more electricity if it is showing less current?

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors

A air conditioner has label 9 amp of current and 2000 Watt. 
But in actual reading it is showing 7 amp.(may be due to any fault, i.e. low Gas in compressor)

Does it consume more electricity or less compared to 2000 Watt ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the supply voltage and power factor? Is it single-phase or three-phase?

Use this information on [this page](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/kva-reactive-d_886.html) to calculate Active Power.

Off-the-cuff, the amount of current doesn't seem unreasonable for a 240 VAC single-phase system but more details are needed to give you a better answer.

Comment: Supply voltage is 240 V (Single phase)